# Is it okay to ask for an update after offer with another company?

Tags: hiring

So I had an interview more or less three weeks ago with a company that I really like. Of course, I've gone to other interviews with other companies. The thing is, I've gotten two offers already with those other companies. And I have a deadline with those two to make a decision. I was ready to accept one of those offers already, but I had a call from the first company and they asked me to send a certain requirement and they might give me an offer. (At least that's what they were insinuating during the call) The deadline for those two companies are nearing, and I really want to get accepted in the first one. I'm just not sure if they're really gonna offer or not - I just don't want to be left without a job when that deadline comes.

So my question is: Is it okay for me to ask for an update and inform them of the offers? Or should I just let it be, and accept one of the offers when the time comes?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: Is it okay for me to ask for an update and inform them of the offers? Or should I just let it be, and accept one of the offers when the time comes?

Three weeks is quite a long time. I'd say just be honest with the company that you really like - tell them that you're really keen to work for them over other places you've interviewed, but you have other offers on the table you need to take by (some date), so if you don't have a firm offer by then you'll need to walk away.